# How to change the title of my Spinner Menu

Tags: java, android

I am wondering is there a possibility to change the Title Text on my Spinner Menu?

I see the Prompt Title field id in the component, but i dont know if its possible to avoid that it always take the first row data from my arrayList....

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                CategoriesConsumer.categories);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: If I get you right you want to show a custom "title" in the spinner field as long as no item was selected by the user. right? Have you ever found a way? I want to achieve the same thing...

Answer (score 3):

Hmm?

Unless I'm mistaken then you've already mentioned it. For XML inside the Spinner component:

```
android:prompt="This is my title"
```

And in code:

```
spinner.setPrompt("This is my title");
```

Not sure what you mean about avoiding that it takes row data from your ArrayList...

Comment: Cool i am testing that right now!

Comment: If it doesn't then I'll be back in an hour or so when my commute from work is over ;)

Comment: Look, i am trying to change the title on the layout view where the Spinner Composant is showed. 
The title you mean is just changed when the menu is diplayed after clicked it ! you understand?

Comment: So you're not asking how to change the title text, you're asking how to change the default selected item? Call setSelection to pick a position from your adapter.

Comment: Yes exactly adamp, I am looking for changing the default selected text on the UILayout, before it have been selected !